# When run app at the first time, iphone will be reboot in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm facing a hard problem. When I run my app on iphone 5s, my iphone will be reboot (Apple logo appear) in the first time, but then run my app again, it can run fine. It just happen when run in the first time and run on iphone 5s ( iphone 4s and iphone 5 dont encounter this issue). And when it reboot, Xcode console shows message error :

```
 dyld`_dyld_start:
0x2befd028:  mov    r8, sp
0x2befd02c:  sub    sp, sp, #16
0x2befd030:  bic    sp, sp, #7
0x2befd034:  ldr    r3, [pc, #112]            ; _dyld_start + 132
0x2befd038:  sub    r0, pc, #8
0x2befd03c:  ldr    r3, [r0, r3]
0x2befd040:  sub    r3, r0, r3
0x2befd044:  ldr    r0, [r8]
0x2befd048:  ldr    r1, [r8, #4]
0x2befd04c:  add    r2, r8, #8
0x2befd050:  ldr    r4, [pc, #88]             ; _dyld_start + 136
0x2befd054:  add    r4, r4, pc
0x2befd058:  str    r4, [sp]
0x2befd05c:  add    r4, sp, #12
0x2befd060:  str    r4, [sp, #4]
0x2befd064:  blx    0x2befd0d0                ; dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*)
0x2befd068:  ldr    r5, [sp, #12]
0x2befd06c:  cmp    r5, #0
0x2befd070:  bne    0x2befd07c                ; _dyld_start + 84
0x2befd074:  add    sp, r8, #4
0x2befd078:  bx     r0
0x2befd07c:  mov    lr, r5
0x2befd080:  mov    r5, r0
0x2befd084:  ldr    r0, [r8, #4]
0x2befd088:  add    r1, r8, #8
0x2befd08c:  add    r2, r1, r0, lsl #2
0x2befd090:  add    r2, r2, #4
0x2befd094:  mov    r3, r2
0x2befd098:  ldr    r4, [r3]
0x2befd09c:  add    r3, r3, #4
0x2befd0a0:  cmp    r4, #0
0x2befd0a4:  bne    0x2befd098                ; _dyld_start + 112
0x2befd0a8:  bx     r5
0x2befd0ac:  strheq r3, [r2], -r0
0x2befd0b0:  .long  0xffffefa4                ; unknown opcode
```

This code is when start up app:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        loginViewControl = [[LoginTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginTab" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        loginViewControl = [[LoginTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginTab~ipad" bundle:nil];
    }

   // loginViewControl = [[LoginTab alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *objNavigationController=[[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginViewControl]autorelease];

    self.window.rootViewController = objNavigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    completeTab = [[CompletedTab alloc] init];

   // photoButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 430, 160, 49);

    return YES;
}
```

I found on the internet but i can not find out the solution for this issue. Anybody know this issue and solution? Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you post some code? - What are you doing when the app starts? e.g. any particularly weird code etc. Also have you tried coping the code into a fresh project and checking if the issue occurs there too?

Comment: Not sure if it is related. But this post says its a bug similar to what you described. http://www.gizmodo.co.uk/2014/01/iphone-ios-7s-screen-of-death-reboot-bug-to-be-ironed-out-by-7-1/ If you are developer, could you not install the 7.1 beta to see? Otherwise a bit of patience and it will work?

Comment: Add lots of NSLog() statements, narrow down where the code is crashing by watching the console.

Comment: Or just set a breakpoint in XCode and step through your startup sequence while debugging

Comment: @JohnWoods: I updated the code when start up my app in my question